# iptables can't match https traffic

Tags: iptables, https, openwrt

I got a WiFi router(xiaomi HD) with customized openwrt OS and I added some   iptables rules trying to count https traffic, but it seems the rule can't match https traffic.
Here are the rules(on router):

```
root@XiaoQiang: iptables -nvxL FORWARD
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 22 packets, 3134 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
       4     1668            tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:443
       7      713            tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
      22     3134            all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

I initiated https traffic with(on laptop):

```
xxx-Pro:traffic_statistics user$ wget https://downloads.openwrt.org/releases/18.06.1/targets/ipq806x/generic/packages/libc_1.1.19-1_arm_cortex-a15_neon-vfpv4.ipk
root@xxx# ll libc_1.1.19-1_arm_cortex-a15_neon-vfpv4.ipk
-rw-r--r--@ 1 tengjp  staff  226903  8 17 19:46 libc_1.1.19-1_arm_cortex-a15_neon-vfpv4.ipk
```

and it succeed, but the iptables counters do not seem to match the size of the file downloaded.

If I add a reject rule for port 443, it DOES match the rule and wget can't even establish the connection(on laptop):

```
xxx-Pro:traffic_statistics user$ wget https://downloads.openwrt.org/releases/18.06.1/targets/ipq806x/generic/packages/libc_1.1.19-1_arm_cortex-a15_neon-vfpv4.ipk
--2019-01-22 15:29:50--  https://downloads.openwrt.org/releases/18.06.1/targets/ipq806x/generic/packages/libc_1.1.19-1_arm_cortex-a15_neon-vfpv4.ipk
 downloads.openwrt.org (downloads.openwrt.org)... 148.251.78.235
connecting downloads.openwrt.org (downloads.openwrt.org)|148.251.78.235|:443... 

failure：Operation timed out。
retrying

--2019-01-22 15:31:06--  (retry times： 2)  https://downloads.openwrt.org/releases/18.06.1/targets/ipq806x/generic/packages/libc_1.1.19-1_arm_cortex-a15_neon-vfpv4.ipk
connecting downloads.openwrt.org (downloads.openwrt.org)|148.251.78.235|:443... failure：Operation timed out。
retrying

// on router
root@XiaoQiang: iptables -nvxL FORWARD
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 91 packets, 10410 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
      95     5399 REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:443 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
       7      312            tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:443
      84     4713            tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
     157    15471            all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Also tried with http traffic, it works OK.

Router OS info:

```
root@XiaoQiang:/userdisk# uname -a
Linux XiaoQiang 3.4.103 #1 MiWiFi-R3D-2.29.4 SMP PREEMPT Thu Dec 13 08:44:30 UTC 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux
root@XiaoQiang:/userdisk# iptables -v
iptables v1.4.21: no command specified
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
root@XiaoQiang:/userdisk# cat /proc/version 
Linux version 3.4.103 (jenkins@f408c3ab886a) (gcc version 4.8.5 (crosstool-NG crosstool-ng-1.22.0) ) #1 MiWiFi-R3D-2.29.4 SMP PREEMPT Thu Dec 13 08:44:30 UTC 2018
root@XiaoQiang:/userdisk# cat /etc/openwrt_release 
DISTRIB_ID="QSDK"
DISTRIB_RELEASE="IPQ806X.LN"
DISTRIB_REVISION="unknown"
DISTRIB_CODENAME="standard"
DISTRIB_TARGET="ipq806x/MiWiFi"
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="QSDK Standard IPQ806X.LN"
```

Tried with another router with different OS version, both http and https works OK with the same iptables rule:

```
Linux PandoraBox 3.14.44 #7 Mon Jun 8 22:23:15 CST 2015 mips GNU/Linux
iptables v1.4.21
```

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: Also tried to clean up all iptables rules and add only one rule, still have the problem.

Comment: Tried with xiaomi router pro, OS version: `Linux XiaoQiang 3.10.14 #1 MiWiFi-R3P-2.13.65 SMP Fri Aug 25 15:07:33 CST 2017 mips GNU/Linux`, both http and https works OK. Guess it has something to do with kernel version.